# post increment about an expression

Tags: c

I was asked the output of following expression :-

```
I=10;
I++;
I++;
I++;
```

What will be the value of I at the end of this code. As per my knowledge, post increment in c means that first perform any other task like assignment ,printf etc and after it incteement the value of variable. Similarly in this case , first I should be 10, then I should be 10 and then it would be 11. But final answer came out to be 10 . how ?

Comment: Neither 10 nor 11. By the end of that code, the value of `I` is 13. You could always run it and find that out for yourself...

Comment: That's 4 expressions.  Did you mean `printf("%d %d %d %d", I = 10, I++, I++, I++)`?

Answer (score 2):

The awnser should be 13.

```
int i = 10;
i++;
i++;
i++;
printf("%d", i);
```

test it urself

Answer (score 2):

It would have been a nine-line program to demonstrate what happens to `I` in your question. In an expression containing `I++;`, `I` is used then incremented. In your example, since `I` is not used in any statement, you might have well used `++I` to pre-increment it. But if a statement uses or tests `I` more than once, or contains a part that might not be executed, you must increment `I` afterwards.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int I = 10;
    I++;
    I++;
    I++;
    printf ("%d\n", I);     // prints 13

    if (1 || I++)           // I++ is not executed
        printf ("%d\n", I); // prints 13

    if (1 && I++)           // I++ is executed
        printf ("%d\n", I); // prints 14
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

lets create an `int i = 10;`

```
i++;
```

is essentially the same as:

```
i = i + 1;
```

There is a slight difference though:

If you `printf("%d", i++);`

the printed value will be 10 since a `++` postfix will increment the value only after the value is used and `i` will equal 11 only on the next line, when:

`printf("%d", i + 1);`

will print 11 since it will be calculated before `printf` runs and `i` it self wont be changed since we didn't assign a value to it, we only used it to calculate a new value.

If you want behavior exactly the same as `i = i + 1;` you can use a `++` prefix like:

`printf("%d", ++i);`

in which case 11 will be printed and the value of `i` will increment by 1.

In your code you increment `i` using a `++` postfix 3 times without actually using `i` so all the code dose is increments `i` by one, there times. So at the end of the code `i` is equal to 13.

You can find more information on operators here:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm